# Get PDF from Project

Tags: java, pdf, attachment

Hi and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have a PDF file which is found in one of the project's folders. I need to load the PDF into a File type. How can I do that? We're taking in Java.

Comment: For which purpose do you want to open the PDF?

Comment: I need to get it in a File format, so I can send it as an attachment to the e-mail we're sending. The API insists that we send an File[] where each item in the array is an attachment

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the [proper constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) offered by File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists the `File` class in `java.io` package.
The usage would be something like:

`File pdf = new File("full_pdf_filename");`

Check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to see the full documentation of the `File` class.